# Can you have an echo in a echo PHP

Tags: php, echo

Im trying to get the second echo to echo out the message but the first echo dont let me.
I know the second echo works and the first too but when I but them together it wont work.
Also im new to this so help is appreciated.

```
echo
'<h1 class="text-center text-info" >J!inder</h1> <br> 
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-around" >
    
    'echo $create->profilerand();'
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use concat

```
echo
'<h1 class="text-center text-info" >J!inder</h1> <br> 
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-around" >
    
    ' . $create->profilerand(). '
    </div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP automatically uses the original echo, so you don't need it when using a variable.

```
echo
'<h1 class="text-center text-info" >J!inder</h1> <br> 
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-around" >
    
    '.$create->profilerand().'
    </div>';
```

The code removes the `echo` and `;`, then replaces it with `.` which is just the joining character. `echo` is just a print function, and prints it onto the page. You can't print a printer. This also means you can use variables in variables (e.g. `$whatever = "Lorem ".$create->profilerand()." ipsum";`).